# Dynamically changing functions within functions in Python

Tags: python, string, exec, function

Trying to do some dynamic function changing in Python based on pulling functions from strings:

The goal is being able to replace a function with a new function interpreted from a string during runtime and based on user input.

I have been trying to use the exec function as a way of interpreting text as a function, but it seems to not work when regarding updating functions within other functions.

What I have so far is

```
>>> exec( "def test(x): print( x + 8 )" )
>>> test(8)
16
```

This works fine, though-

```
>>> def newTest( newTestString ):
        initString = "def test(x): "
        exec( initString + newTestString )
>>> newTest( "print( x + 20 )" )
>>> test(10)
18
```

is failing, can exec be used within functions?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

`exec()` can be used in functions just fine, you just need to remember in what namespace the new object has been created. You need to return it from your *local namespace*:

```
>>> def newTest(newTestString):
...     initString = "def test(x): "
...     exec(initString + newTestString)
...     return test
... 
>>> newTest("print x + 20")
<function test at 0x10b06f848>
>>> test = newTest("print x + 20")
>>> test(10)
30
```

This only works in Python 2, where the normal local namespace optimisations are disabled when `exec` is used. In Python 3, give `exec()` a namespace to create the new object *in*, then retrieve the new function and return it:

```
>>> def newTest(newTestString):
...     initString = "def test(x): "
...     ns = {}
...     exec(initString + newTestString, ns)
...     return ns['test']
... 
>>> newTest("print(x + 20)")
<function test at 0x110337b70>
>>> test = newTest("print(x + 20)")
>>> test(10)
30
```

This method works just as well in Python 2, with the added advantage that the local namespace optimisations are not disabled either.

In principle you can instruct `exec` to work directly in your global namespace too:

```
exec(initString + newTestString, globals())
```

but like all globals such side-effects should be avoided.

Comment: could you `exec string in globals()`? (if I remember the python2.x syntax correctly) -- And I think somewhere along the way, `exec` started to accept a tuple for compatability with python3's exec function...

Comment: @mgilson: you can, but the preferred method would be to create a new namespace instead.

Comment: I think that the preferred method would be to not use `exec` at all ... ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: I quite agree! I've had use for `exec` in the past however, where I needed to generate a function object with the exact same signature as one I was wrapping (as introspection was going to be applied to it).

Comment: @mgilson: using `exec` was cleaner than using `compile` and the function type constructor.

Comment: I'm not saying that there are _no_ uses for `exec` (or `eval`), but the set of problems they _should_ be used for and the set of problems the _are_ used for are very different.  The use that you're talking about is the approach that is taken in the [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module I believe -- although I often wish that `functools.wraps` could actually transfer the function signature for introspection purposes...